# Parsing Error from XML to Html Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i am getting data from `XML` file and show it into `HTML` file the `XML` files contains sub-sub-child of nodes
My XML Files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<projects>
<project title="title1" subtitle="subtitle1">
    <text>First Tesxt</text>
    <images>
        <image url="1/176.png"></image>
        <image url="1/178.png"></image>
        <image url="1/173.png"></image>
    </images>
</project>
<project title="title2" subtitle="subtitle2">
    <text>Second Test</text>
    <images>
        <image url="2/164.png"></image>
        <image url="2/175.png"></image>
        <image url="2/1767.png"></image>
    </images>
</project>
```

The HTML Javascript Part is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("projects.xml");

var length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("project").length;
for(i=0; i<length;i++)
{
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("project")[i].getAttribute("title"));
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("project")[i].getAttribute("subtitle"));
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("text")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var lengthImage = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("images")[i].childNodes[0].length;
    for(var j=0; j<lengthImage; j++)
    {
        alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[j].getAttribute("url"));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the images node cannot display correctly it always iterates 4 time in `loop`

Comment: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName` searches the entire XML document so when you call `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")`, the query is not restricted to your current project.

Comment: so what I should  do in this case? @David

Answer (score 0):

1 - Your XML doesn't have `</projects>` on the last line.
2 - `var lengthImage = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("images")[i].childNodes.length; //childNodes  does't need "[0]"`